# JavaFx 2.0 Menu

Tags: menu, javafx, javafx-2

I want to have a menu for my program. And I like the standard Menu look and all, but I  want to place a "logout-button" on the far right side of the menu-bar.. is it possible to place it there WITHOUT having to fill up the whole menu-bar with entries?

Sincerely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Use the  [HBox#setHgrow();](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow%28javafx.scene.Node,%20javafx.scene.layout.Priority%29). This javadoc page also has an example how to use it in "**Optional Layout Constraints**" section. Following is taken from javadoc.

For example, if an hbox needs the TextField to be allocated all extra space:

```
     HBox hbox = new HBox();
     TextField field = new TextField();
     HBox.setHgrow(field, Priority.ALWAYS);
     hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Search:"), field, new Button("Go"));
```

Briefly speaking, set `Priority.ALWAYS` for the button (or any control) just before the "logout-button" in a `HBox`. More advanced example is here: [Using Built-In Layout Panes : Example 1-4](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDJFBAE)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D
Here's another Question I have:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315774/javafx-2-0-menu-menubar-menuitem

Comment: This is a nice solution for Nodes in HBoxes. But how would one apply it to Menus in a MenuBar? Did I miss something?

Comment: @andreas. With a default menu style, putting 2 different menuBars into HBox and giving a "ALWAYS" priority to the first menuBar visually accomplishes the desired effect for menus in a menubar(s).