# JavaFX 2.0 Activating a Menu like a MenuItem

Tags: menu, javafx, menuitem, javafx-2, menubar

I'm making a `MenuBar`, and I wan't the functionality to press a `Menu` like: "File" and then execute a action. Such like opening an other fxml, or an example where some output is written.

I want the functionality of a `MenuItem` (lie "About") in a  `Menu` like "File".

```
package model;

import static java.lang.System.out;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Example of creating menus in JavaFX.
 * 
 * @author Dustin
 */
public class JavaFxMenus extends Application
{
   /**
    * Build menu bar with included menus for this demonstration.
    * 
    * @param menuWidthProperty Width to be bound to menu bar width.
    * @return Menu Bar with menus included.
    */
   private MenuBar buildMenuBarWithMenus(final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty menuWidthProperty)
   {
      final MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

      // Prepare left-most 'File' drop-down menu
      final Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");

      menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenu);
      //menuBar.getOnMouseClicked().handle(this);


      // Prepare 'Examples' drop-down menu
      final Menu examplesMenu = new Menu("JavaFX 2.0 Examples");
      examplesMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Text Example"));
      examplesMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Objects Example"));
      examplesMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Animation Example"));
      menuBar.getMenus().add(examplesMenu);

      // Prepare 'Help' drop-down menu
      final Menu helpMenu = new Menu("Help");
      helpMenu.setOnAction(null);

      final MenuItem searchMenuItem = new MenuItem("Search");
      searchMenuItem.setDisable(true);
      helpMenu.getItems().add(searchMenuItem);
      final MenuItem onlineManualMenuItem = new MenuItem("Online Manual");
      onlineManualMenuItem.setVisible(false);
      helpMenu.getItems().add(onlineManualMenuItem);
      helpMenu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
      final MenuItem aboutMenuItem =
         MenuItemBuilder.create()
                        .text("About")
                        .onAction(
                            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                            {
                               @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e)
                               {
                                  out.println("You clicked on About!");
                               }
                            })
                        .accelerator(
                            new KeyCodeCombination(
                               KeyCode.A, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN))
                        .build();             
      helpMenu.getItems().add(aboutMenuItem);
      menuBar.getMenus().add(helpMenu);

      // bind width of menu bar to width of associated stage
      menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(menuWidthProperty);

      return menuBar;
   }

   /**
    * Start of JavaFX application demonstrating menu support.
    * 
    * @param stage Primary stage.
    */
   @Override
   public void start(final Stage stage)
   {
      stage.setTitle("Creating Menus with JavaFX 2.0");
      final Group rootGroup = new Group();
      final Scene scene = new Scene(rootGroup, 800, 400, Color.WHEAT);



      final MenuBar menuBar = buildMenuBarWithMenus(stage.widthProperty());
      rootGroup.getChildren().add(menuBar);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }

   /**
    * Main executable function for running examples.
    * 
    * @param arguments Command-line arguments: none expected.
    */
   public static void main(final String[] arguments)
   {
      Application.launch(arguments);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK, A `Menu`, if has not any added submenu or `Menuitem`s, does not fire events neither on click, on shown nor on hide. However the workaround is to set its graphic where this graphic node will handle mouse clicks for example,

```
Label menuLabel = new Label("File");
menuLabel.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

        Stage myDialog = new Stage();
        myDialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

        Scene myDialogScene = new Scene(VBoxBuilder.create()
            .children(new Text("Hello! it's My Dialog."))
            .alignment(Pos.CENTER)
            .padding(new Insets(10))
            .build());

        myDialog.setScene(myDialogScene);
        myDialog.show();
    }
});
Menu fileMenuButton = new Menu();
fileMenuButton.setGraphic(menuLabel);
menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenuButton);
```

A drawback of this approach is that the label do not cover all spaces of the menu resulting clicking on edges of menu is not triggering the mouse event. See this by uncommenting `menuLabel.setStyle` line above. But this can be resolved by playing with `CSS` styles I think.
Code is partially taken from [Create Dialog using Stage](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/02/create-dialog-using-stage.html). You can also load an `FXML` file into the `myDialog` stage using the `FXMLLoader`. There are lots of examples about it on the net.

Answer (score 4):

Recently i had the same problem, this is what i did

```
@FXML private Menu myMenu;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    myMenu.setGraphic(
        ButtonBuilder.create()
            .text("btnText")
            .onAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    //TODO
             } })
            .build()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining with the answer from our friend [@Dota2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788606/dota2), i built a helper class to trigger the `Menu`'s `onAction(Menu menu)` event even if it does not have any `MenuItem` inside. Here is the static helper method:

```
public static void onAction(Menu menu)
{
    final MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();

    menu.getItems().add(menuItem);
    menu.addEventHandler(Menu.ON_SHOWN, event -> menu.hide());
    menu.addEventHandler(Menu.ON_SHOWING, event -> menu.fire());
}
```

Then you call:

```
YourHelperClass.onAction(myMenu);
```

And ready! I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I faced the same issue, this was my way out:

I had a menuItem in the menu, which was to behave as if the menuItem is clicked (in your case `File` menu). So what you can do is have a menuItem `Dummy_menuItem`

```
final Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Dummy_menuItem"));
menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenu);
```

and then on click of `File` menu, fire the `Dummy_menuItem` menuItem or any functionality you wish to have. To identify which menu should have this property, I used `numberOfMenuItems` to get the number of menuItems in the menus in menubar

```
if (numberOfMenuItems == 1) {
    menu.showingProperty().addListener(
        (observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                // the first menuItem is triggered
                menu.getItems().get(0).fire();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

the outcome is that the `Dummy_menuItem` is triggered without the context displaying the menuItem on click of `File` menu or any menu that has one menuItem. So it appears as if you clicked the `File` menu and were redirected to another page or whatever.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This works perfectly and should be the accepted answer. No need to modify graphics, just make use of the `showingProperty`.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work if you have combination of menus with 1 child and with 1+ child.. if you click to rolldown the multichild menu (no action needed, that is ok) and move your mouse over tu one child menu, the fire is triggered on hover, without need to do a mouse-click

Answer (score -4):

I think you can't allow any action on the main Menu label.

However, you can create a stackpane, and fill it with text and a menu bar.