# javafx menubar menuitem

Tags: menu, javafx, menuitem, menubar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaFX 2.0 Activating a Menu like a MenuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315774/javafx-2-0-activating-a-menu-like-a-menuitem)

I want a JavaFX `MenuItem` directly in the JavaFX `MenuBar` *and not be forced* to add a `Menu` and then a `MenuItem`.

More precise, I want a menu:

```
File   View     About
exit   view1
...
```

Where clicking on "About" leads directly to the about window.

It seems now I can only make a `MenuBar`, then add a `Menu` "About" and beneath add a `MenuItem` "About" as in:

```
File   View     About
exit   view1    about
...
```

How to work around this limitation of JavaFX `MenuBar`?

Comment: You mean, like this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10315774/422353

Comment: See comments there. I tried it but it does not work.

Comment: Updated my answer to the similar question here [JavaFX 2.0 Activating a Menu like a MenuItem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10315774/682495).